# I want to disable only one of the radio button

Tags: angular, radio-button, radio-group

I have an array of obj at
**app.component.ts**

```
AccountTypeArr:any[] = [
    {id:30,accountName:'Bank Account'},
    {id:25,accountName:'Cash Account'}
  ]
```

iterating array of obj in mat-radio-group at
**app.component.html**

```
<mat-radio-group aria-label="Select an option"
 formControlName="underGroupId" (click)="onClickRadioChange()">
  <mat-radio-button *ngFor="let aTypes of AccountTypeArr"
   [checked]="aTypes.id == 30" [value]="aTypes.id"
  (click)="onCheckAccountType(aTypes.id)">{{aTypes.accountName}}</mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
```

Comment: What do you mean with `I want to disable only one of the radio button`? Your code currently doesn't disable any of them.

Comment: Can you please share the complete code snippet or you can share working snippet then we can able to help you.

Comment: Or here is my old snippet may be it will help you. And let me know if you need more help.
https://angular-ivy-hmvb7r.stackblitz.io

@Cuzy I think he is looking something like this. but indeed he is not provided complete code and details.

Comment: Actually, I'll get underGroupId =25 OR 30 from backend side while editing form, So by default  I need to make it checked and whatever is already set I want to make it disable

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the criteria by which you want to disable the button. You could either add a property to all the objects

```
AccountTypeArr:any[] = [
    {id:30,accountName:'Bank Account', isDisabled: false,},
    {id:25,accountName:'Cash Account', isDisabled: true}
]

<mat-radio-group aria-label="Select an option"
    formControlName="underGroupId" (click)="onClickRadioChange()">
    <mat-radio-button *ngFor="let aTypes of AccountTypeArr"
    [checked]="aTypes.id == 30" [value]="aTypes.id" 
    [disabled]="aTypes.isDisabled"
    (click)="onCheckAccountType(aTypes.id)">{{aTypes.accountName}}</mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
```

Or you could have the evaluation in the HTML

```
<mat-radio-group aria-label="Select an option"
    formControlName="underGroupId" (click)="onClickRadioChange()">
    <mat-radio-button *ngFor="let aTypes of AccountTypeArr"
    [checked]="aTypes.id == 30" [value]="aTypes.id" 
    [disabled]="aTypes.id < 30"
    (click)="onCheckAccountType(aTypes.id)">{{aTypes.accountName}}</mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
```